# Dropdown help java

Tags: java, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get dropdown list value from form and back to form if someone is updating existing record.. I tried to do this way..

```
public String getOptionDropDownList()
    {

        if(getOption().compareTo("Y") == 0)
                _ddlOption.setSelectedItem("Y");
        else {(getOption().compareTo("N") == 0)
                _ddlOption.setSelectedItem("N");
        }
        return _ddlOption.getHTMLString();
    }
```

but i am getting this error..

```
compile:
     [exec] com\jack\example\SampleBean.java:161: not a statement
     [exec]             else (getOption().compareTo("N") == 0)
     [exec]                      ^
     [exec] com\jack\example\SampleBean.java:162: ';' expected
     [exec]                             _ddlOption.setSelectedItem("N");
     [exec]                                 ^
     [exec] 2 errors
```

Can somebody explain to me what I am doing wrong, or is there other way to do this?

ddlOption is declared as new Dropdown
getOption holds what is in the database

Comment: More context would be helpful here.  Are you using Swing to build these components?

Answer (score 7):

Not else. You should write

```
else if (getOption().compareTo("N") == 0) { 
   _ddlOption.setSelectedItem("N");
}
```

You should write `getOption().equals("N")` instead of `getOption().compareTo("N") == 0` it's easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have missed the "if" after else

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant do have an else if statement like this one:

```
else if (getOption().compareTo("N") == 0) {
  _ddlOption.setSelectedItem("N");
}
```